# snakeYAML JAVA: using the object produced

Tags: java, android, yaml, snakeyaml

I am attempting to use snakeYAML to load a YAML file into an object in an Android Java Class. How do I access the members of the resulting object?

```
Yaml yaml = new Yaml();
Object data = yaml.load(questionsStream);
Log.v(TAG2,data.toString());
```

The output is:

03-07 18:15:55.637: VERBOSE/Q_Engine Load Questions(615): [{Answer=Sun Jun 25 01:00:00 GMT+01:00 1950, ID=8, Meta Info={Main Topics=[Korean War]}, Obscurity=1, Question=When did the Korean War begin?}, etc...

I want to iterate through the list of Maps and access their members by their keywords.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Replace the second line with:

```
List<Map<String, Object>> data = (List<Map<String, Object>>) yaml.load(questionsStream);
```

The `Object`s from inside the `Map` can be cast to `Maps` or `Lists` and iterated through the same way, depending on the yaml file structure.

Answer (score 1):

Cast your data to list of Maps and iterate.